# Packet or URL capture what do they browse

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openvpn

Now I am studying Internet/Virtural Networking via expressvpn for secure my internet connection. But I have some incomprehensible things. Assume that on one room, there is wireless hub exists for route to each 2 pc to connect internet as following as below.

[Internet Connection on the room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t88pi.png)

The computer A can control wireless hub such as accessing wireless hub admin panel and connect internet by directly. But B does not access internet directly and access internet via OpenVPN server for security. At this point, does the computer A capture packets or url from B when B access internet? Exactly, if B access www.google.com via ExpressVPN, does the computer A capture that url correctly?

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @IporSircer. So is it impossible to capture url or packets by using some tools such as wireshark and so on?

Comment: that's the goal why people uses vpn.